# Starting jetty outside of ${jetty.home} in Windows with logback

Tags: jetty

My goal is to set jetty to run as a service and figured I should have it run in command line first. My current aim is to be able to run jetty from root path. Once that's done, I can then set the same command to run as a service via https://nssm.cc/.

**The issue**

The webapp I am deploying in this Jetty instance uses logback to manage it's logging `<file>logs/app.log</file>`

This works as expected.
`C:\jetty>java -jar start.jar`

This does not `C:\>java -jar C:\jetty\start.jar`. (Note the different cmd path). Jetty can't figure out correct paths for log files. After some testing, I was able to rectify the path issue but still jetty is complaining about not being able to find the log file, even though I see it exists. So, permissions issue perhaps? I go ahead and give everyone full read and write access to the entire folder. No dice, still the same error.

**Command I run now**

`C:\>java -Djetty.base=C:\jetty -Duser.dir=C:\jetty -jar C:\jetty\start.jar` but the error persists.

```
....
12:11:51,095 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [logs/app.log]
12:11:51,111 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - Failed to create parent directories for [C:\jetty\logs\app.log]
12:11:51,111 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[FILE] - openFile(logs/app.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs\app.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: logs\app.log (The system cannot find the path specified)
....
```

Jetty version is 9.4.9.v20180320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a proper `${jetty.base}` directory, outside of of the `${jetty.home}` directory.

Next, get yourself a fresh copy of `jetty-home` (or the `jetty-distribution` which really only adds documentation, demos, and sample bases to `jetty-home`).

[http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g:"org.eclipse.jetty" AND a:"jetty-home"](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jetty-home%22)

Unpack that `jetty-home` artifact into a fresh directory.

**Important:**

- Don't touch any content in `jetty-home`
- Don't edit anything in `jetty-home`
- Don't remove anything from `jetty-home`
- Don't add anything into `jetty-home`
- Leave `jetty-home` alone
- Treat `jetty-home` as a read-only directory

> All above bullets apply even if using `jetty-distribution`

Lastly, start jetty per the recommendations in the [Jetty Documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/).

```
> cd \path\to\myjettybase
> java -jar \path\to\jetty-home\start.jar
```

> Note the lack of declared system properties for `-Djetty.home` and `-Djetty.base`, this is important!

This will set up the following important directory properties.

- `jetty.base` will be your CWD, or `\path\to\myjettybase`
- `jetty.home` will be where your `start.jar` was found, aka `\path\to\jetty-home\`
- `user.dir` will be your CWD and point to `\path\to\myjettybase`

What's important, for logging configurations like yours, is the `user.dir` system property.  (aka the current working directory)

The technique you are using where you don't pay attention to the working directory and just attempt to force values into the JVM with system properties is only viable in the simplest of projects and usecases. (your requirements have outgrown that kind of setup)

Comment: I just had to add appropriate modules after which things are working fine. Thanks much!